# Petapoco tt file error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, petapoco

Getting this error when trying to save tt file in petapoco. I have installed petapoco from nuget package manager on a class library but it did not create the Auto generated Models folder as expected. So for play around i have copied the models folder from my old project and placed the same in the class library and specified my connection string configuration in App.config file. and have given correct connection string name and namespace values. But still i am facing this error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Running transformation: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject' in Assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<GetSerializableMembers>b__0(MemberHolder _)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.SerializeMessageParts(ArrayList argsToSerialize)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodReturnMessage..ctor(IMethodReturnMessage mrm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodReturnMessage.SmuggleIfPossible(IMessage msg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoDispatch(Byte[] reqStmBuff, SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMcm, SmuggledMethodReturnMessage& smuggledMrm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatchCallback(Object[] args)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at EnvDTE._DTE.get_ActiveSolutionProjects()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating0DC162F56BA57DF4829DC8F54798CB1DA7D993D6DA58B9167EA329560E9EF6B318CB739601F4F4361C2EBFFAFDC63B9299812AAACEED30548AB7769327D785AF.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetCurrentProject()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating0DC162F56BA57DF4829DC8F54798CB1DA7D993D6DA58B9167EA329560E9EF6B318CB739601F4F4361C2EBFFAFDC63B9299812AAACEED30548AB7769327D785AF.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetConnectionString(String& connectionStringName, String& providerName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating0DC162F56BA57DF4829DC8F54798CB1DA7D993D6DA58B9167EA329560E9EF6B318CB739601F4F4361C2EBFFAFDC63B9299812AAACEED30548AB7769327D785AF.GeneratedTextTransformation.InitConnectionString()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating0DC162F56BA57DF4829DC8F54798CB1DA7D993D6DA58B9167EA329560E9EF6B318CB739601F4F4361C2EBFFAFDC63B9299812AAACEED30548AB7769327D785AF.GeneratedTextTransformation.LoadTables()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating0DC162F56BA57DF4829DC8F54798CB1DA7D993D6DA58B9167EA329560E9EF6B318CB739601F4F4361C2EBFFAFDC63B9299812AAACEED30548AB7769327D785AF.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() SeigAppV1.Services  D:\Projects\SeigAppV1\SeigAppV1.Services\Models\Generated\Database.tt   1
```

Comment: I have observed that I am unable to generate my models' folder in a class library and even in asp.net mvc core 1.1 project. trying to explore the reason

Comment: Any solution? Same problem here. I thought it was fixed after making some changes, closing VS and reopening, but it's back again.

Comment: This is still a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered same issue with text template from Dapper.SimpleCrud, and is also looking for a solution for VS 2017 release 15.5, although VS 2017 preview 15.5 has no issue (with a reference to Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform).

At same time, hope below workaround could keep you moving forward:

> Right click .tt file and then "Debug T4 Template"